# Unity - Async/Await too slow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm downloading a texture from a server. Running the code in the editor takes a few second to download it. But when I build it and run the .exe the download takes multiple minutes. Is there a reason for it? Any build option?

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(PATH);
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

byte[] data = new byte[response.ContentLength];

int bytesRead = 0, count = (int)response.ContentLength;
while (bytesRead < count) {
    int read = await stream.ReadAsync(data, bytesRead, count - bytesRead);

    if (read <= 0)
        continue;

    bytesRead += read;
}
```

**EDIT:**
The Problem is awaiting. Awaiting `Stream.Read` called in `Task.Factory.StartNew` results in the same behavior. Values from Task Manager Ethernet Profiling:

**Async:** Editor: 47Mbps; Build 4.4Mbps
**Sync:** Editor = Build: 61Mbps

Comment: This code is incorrect: `response.GetResponseStream()` should be called once *outside* the `while` and stored in a variable with `using`. And `response` should also be in a `using`

Comment: @Charlieface Sry. The code is actually split into multiple methods, but I joined them to make the code section in this question smaller. It's actually just called once and passed as a parameter.

Comment: I would have expected `if(read == 0) break;` rather than `continue;`. What is the app doing in the meantime? In other words, is the async code getting blocked because the UI thread is not idling?

Comment: The UI thread is doing the same thing it does in the editor. Rendering a 64x64 isometric checkerboard pattern (1 mesh, 1 texture). That should be done in <1us so no nothing is blocking the UI thread.

Comment: Depends how often it's doing it: if it's doing it only on `Paint` (or some other event) then yes, but not if it's continually doing it in a loop. Can you setup a bit of logging on this download function to check the progress and see where it's getting held up?

Comment: OnPaint? I'm not using WinForms, WPF or UWP. The Mesh is created once, the texture is created once and then Unity renders it at 60 FPS

Comment: `But when I build it and run the .exe` Are you running it on Windows?

Comment: @mjwills Yes I build it with x86_64 architecture and run it on Windows

Comment: Which _specific_ line took multiple minutes?

Comment: The whole downloading process, so the whole while loop takes multiple minutes to finish. But because `read` is always at 8000 in editor and build, it seems like `ReadAsync` takes longer.

Comment: Did you add logging to identify which was the slow bit? Or are you guessing which bit is slow?

Comment: I used the `Stopwatch` to make sure. In the editor, it takes 0-1ms for `ReadAsync` to finish one call. In the build it takes 16ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem is, that `async/await` does not work the way it 'usually' works. After reading [this](https://gametorrahod.com/unity-and-async-await/) article I changed the code and it works fine. Async/Await in Unity actually works more or less the same as the coroutines do. So awaiting an async method waits for a minimum of one frame. That's where this 16ms execution time comes from (1s / 60FPS = 16ms). So wrapping the download code in a task, changing `ReadyAsync` to `Read`, and only awaiting this task solved the problem. Now I have 61Mbps and async download.